# Reformat XML to get separate datasets (open / close tags conditionally?)

Tags: xml, xslt

A software which I (unfortunately) have to use produces an XML file with multiple datasets (see the following example: "Document 1", "Document 2", ...) but without separating them by a wrapping `<document>` tag. It looks like this:

```
<print>
    <section>
        <col1>*****</col1>
        <col2>Document 1</col2>
    </section>
    <section>
        <col1>Title</col1>
        <col2>Title 1</col2>
    </section>
    <section>
        <col1>Year</col1>
        <col2>2011</col2>
    </section>

    <section />

    <section>
        <col1>*****</col1>
        <col2>Document 2</col2>
    </section>
    <section>
        <col1>Title</col1>
        <col2>Title 2</col2>
    </section>
    <section>
        <col1>Year</col1>
        <col2>2012</col2>
    </section>

    <section />

    <section>
        <col1>*****</col1>
        <col2>Document 3</col2>
    </section>
    <section>
        <col1>Title</col1>
        <col2>Title 3</col2>
    </section>
    <section>
        <col1>Year</col1>
        <col2>2013</col2>
    </section>

    <section />

    ...

</print>
```

As you can see, every new "document" starts with `<col1>*****</col1>` in its first `<section></section>` tag and ends with (or to be more specific: is followed by) an empty `<section />` tag.

What I want to do is to take out each `<col2>` value and put it into a wrapping tag, so finally I should get separated datasets of the documents. The result should look like this:

```
<print>

    <document>
        <docno>Document 1</docno>
        <title>Title 1</title>
        <year>2011</year> 
    </document>

    <document>
        <docno>Document 2</docno>
        <title>Title 2</title>
        <year>2012</year> 
    </document>

    <document>
        <docno>Document 3</docno>
        <title>Title 3</title>
        <year>2013</year> 
    </document>

</print>
```

So I have to get all the `<col2>` values, put them into new elements and wrap them in a `<document>` tag. I tried it with the following XSLT and I have partial success (I can get the `<col2>` values), but within the `<xsl:when>` tag (where I try to wrap the `<col2>` values) it throws an error because the `<document>` tag is not closed immediately:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:template name="content">

        <xsl:if test="col1='*****'">
            <xsl:element name="docno">
                <xsl:value-of select="col2"/>   
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="col1='Title'">
            <xsl:element name="title">
                <xsl:value-of select="col2"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="col1='Year'">
            <xsl:element name="year">
                <xsl:value-of select="col2"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template  match="/">

        <xsl:element name="print">

        <xsl:for-each select="print/section">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="col1='*****'">
                    <xsl:element name="document">
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="not(col1/node())">
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="content"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I found out that in XSLT, opening and closing tags conditionally is not possible, but I'm sure there is another solution how to achieve my goal ... I am just not too experienced to find it. Could someone point me to the right direction? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (in XSLT 2.0)

```
<xsl:template match="print">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="section" 
          group-starting-with="section[starts-with(col2, 'Document')]">   
   <document>
     <docno><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/col2"/>
     ... etc ...
   </document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Eero, thank you also for your answer ... as commented above, I won't be in office the next 1 1/2 weeks, but after that I'll try your solution too.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the late answer. But: I am able to use XSLT 2.0 and your solution works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are more elegant ways of doing this especially if you can use XSLT 2.0, but if you know that there are three `<section>` elements in between every empty `<section/>` element, you could do something simple like this (XSLT 1.0 compatible):

#### Stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="print">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!--
      Only apply the first <section> child of <print> and those <section> children
      whose first preceding <section> sibling is an empty <section/> element
      -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="section[position() = 1
        or preceding-sibling::section[1][not(node())]]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="section">
    <document>
      <!--
      Transform the <col2> child of this <section> into a <docno> elemen
      -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="col2" mode="number"/>
      <!--
      Transform the <col2> element of the first following <section> sibling into
      a <title> element
      -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::section[1]/col2" mode="title"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::section[2]/col2" mode="year"/>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="col2" mode="number">
    <docno>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </docno>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="col2" mode="title">
    <title>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </title>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="col2" mode="year">
    <year>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </year>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Eero, thank you very much for your answer ... I won't be in office the next 1 1/2 weeks, but after that I'll give that a try.

Comment: Hi, +1 for your answer, but as I am able to use XSLT 2.0 I took the more "elegant" solution! Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: No probs! Going with the XSLT2.0 solution is certainly the right thing to do.